Can I manipulate a table directly in pyspark?
I am using pyspark in MS Fabric. I have a logging table, and I am trying to delete older entries from it.
That's easy enough, given:

a table whose name is stored in TABLE_LOG

a column in that table by the name LOG_TIME with dtype TimestampType


The following example would keep only the last two days of logs (very roughly, because of the integer cast):
RUNTIME = current_timestamp()
PERSISTENCE = 2
SECONDS_IN_DAY=24*60*60

log = spark.read.format('delta').load(f'Tables/{TABLE_LOG}')
log = log.withColumn('age', (RUNTIME.cast(IntegerType()) - log[LOG_TIME].cast(IntegerType())) / SECONDS_IN_DAY)
log = log.where(log.age < PERSISTENCE)
log.write.mode('overwrite').format('delta').save(f'Tables/{TABLE_LOG}')

In SQL, you would partition and delete the data in-place, which should be neatly parallel, and thus more efficient.
But I want to keep using pyspark, because the whole environment (including the constants and variables) is in python.
Is it possible to do that using pyspark?

As you have answered, you have to used delta for such transactions as delete/upsert. Don;t forget you can also use pyspark to wrap around a sql query using spark.sql(query goes here)

Okay, answering myself here. It works, at least for delta tables:
import delta
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_add

dt = delta.DeltaTable.forPath(spark, f'Tables/{TABLE_LOG}')
dt.delete(col(LOG_TIME) < date_add(RUNTIME, -PERSISTENCE))

...and that's it. Thank you for listening :-)
